# pythonでストアドに引き渡すファイルパスエラー

Tags: python, sql-server

python初級者です。よろしくお願いします。

## やりたいこと

- pythonからsqlserverのストアドを実行したい
- ストアドの引数はファイルパス

## つまづいているところ

- 引数にファイルパスを指定するところでエラー
- パスの `\` が `\\` になってしまうのが原因だということは何となくわかるのですが、
  どうやって解消したらいいかわかりません

## 試したコード

```
input_file = r'C:\xxxx\ImportData\test.csv'
sql = f"usp_test {input_file}"
_cn.execute(sql)
```

## 実行結果

```
'42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'\\' 付近に不適切な構文があります。 (102) (SQLExecDirectW)"
```

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。
`\` ではなく `/` に書き換えることでうまくきました。
`/` が使えないと思い込んでいました。

```
input_file = 'C:/xxxx/ImportData/test.csv'
```